# Binding QML widgets to a list model, but having some widget only bind to a specific index?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qabstractlistmodel

I'm writing a QML GUI that talks to a monitoring server. In one case, there's 3 grouped remote systems, one is is a master, the other two are slaves. I have the full statuses of each one, but need to show more details for the master system.

So for example I'm receiving an update message containing:

```
{
    systems: {
        1: {
            type: Debian,
            name: system1,
            status: OK,
            detailedStatus1: 123,
            detailedStatus2: xyz
        },
        2: {
            type: Ubuntu,
            name: system2,
            status: OK,
            detailedStatus1: 456,
            detailedStatus2: abc
        },
        3: {
            type: Windows,
            name: system3,
            status: OK,
            detailedStatus1: 789,
            detailedStatus2: def
        }
    },
    currentMaster: (1 or 2 or 3)
}
```

...and I want to show type, name, and status for all 3 systems, but only show detailedStatus1 and detailedStatus2 for the currentMaster system.

What should my QML model be like? Should I have a "masterModel ListModel" that my detailedStatus widgets bind to, and an "allsystems ListModel" for type/name/status, and update masterModel everytime currentMaster changes? Or is there a way to do this from a single "allsystems ListModel" , using currentMaster to know what to bind to? Should I be doing something else altogether?

Comment: Does the currentMaster KNOW that it's the master?

Comment: No. I'm not getting 3 individual messages from each system, I'm getting a single message from a controller/monitoring server, who gives me the status of all systems, and decides who's the master. In general I'm interested in combining the "currentMaster" status to know which allsystemsModel index to bind some extra widgets to, if possible (or be recommended a different approach).

Comment: It's normal for a model to contain more info than is needed for a particular view. You just need to some way for that view to know `if (currentMaster === me) { /* show extra stuff */ }`

Comment: To expose systems informations to QML, a `QObject` derived class could wrap systems information with the following properties : `Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<System> systems, ..)` and `Q_PROPERTY(int currentMaster, ..)`.